# If a cube is rigged on all it's edges. How can I animate it so it tumbles forward forever?

Tags: armature, bones

When I roll a rigged cube over its edge (for instance this example which has no bones on all its edges but anyway -> [How can I rig a cylinder so that when it's rotated its end cap will not penetrate the floor?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/119677/how-can-i-rig-a-cylinder-so-that-when-its-rotated-its-end-cap-will-not-penetrat)), some bones stay behind outside my mesh. So I'm not able to animate a next turn/tumble. Does someone have a solution? It is possible to transfer the bones to a new position in one frame after the first rotation? How does this work?

[image]

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/58225/animating-a-rolling-square-wheel-effect/58292#58292 https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/143046/how-can-i-roll-a-cube-around-its-edges-with-armatures/143049#143049 https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/69731/rotate-a-cube-on-a-plane-using-drivers https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/119677/how-can-i-rig-a-cylinder-so-that-when-its-rotated-its-end-cap-will-not-penetrat

Comment: Thanks for the three links, I checked those out before posting this question. These example only explain how to have an object rotate 'once' over an edge. My question starts exactly 'after' the first roll. How do I solve the second roll/tumble, when the parent bone isn't at the next edge anymore?

Comment: Could you update your original post to focus on that point. Are you sure [this](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/69731/rotate-a-cube-on-a-plane-using-drivers) doesn't address.

Comment: No that link is about drivers, I need the 'bones' solution in order to export my object to Unreal. Thanks for your help nevertheless! Especially the link with the cylinder is quite interesting, I'm checking that one first.I'll try update my post later, although the title states a pretty clear question I suppose?

Answer (score 1):

For anyone who is interested in the future. I found a simple solution. Just add an 'empty' and make it a child of the cube (which behaves as a child to the armature). Make sure the empty is in the same location as the parent's bone head.
Give your parent's bone 2 constrains; 'Copy Rotation' + 'Copy Location' and make the target: the Empty.